# How to build a map or list of related opportunities

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, update

I'm working on building a new trigger that for some reason has me a bit stumped on the best way to query some related data.

I have an array of recently updated opportunities:

```
public void OnAfterUpdate(Opportunity[] updatedOpportunities) {
    //How do I build a Map of related opportunity line items?
    //lineItems = someMap.get(someOpportunityId);
}
```

In order to avoid hitting any governor limits I'd like to get all of the related opportunity line items, but, in a way that they are easily retrieved based on the opportunity id.

I was originally thinking of doing something like:

```
opportunityLineItemsMap = new Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItem>>([SELECT OpportunityId, PricebookEntry.Product2.Name FROM OpportunityLineItem]);
```

However, this obviously isn't valid syntax.  Is there an easy way to build a map like this or am I stuck with a nested loop of iterating over each opportunity and then over each line item to build the data structure myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
List<Opportunity> opptys = [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, PricebookEntry.Product2.Name FROM OpportunityLineItems) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: updatedOpportunities];
```

Then you can reference the list of OpportunityLineItems with something like the following to iterate over each Opportunity and create a map:

```
Map<String, List<OpportunityLineItem>> opportunityLineItemsMap = new Map<String, List<OpportunityLineItem>>();
for (Opportunity oppty : [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, PricebookEntry.Product2.Name FROM OpportunityLineItems) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: updatedOpportunities])
{
  opportunityLineItemsMap.put(oppty.Id, oppty.OpportunityLineItems);
}
```